# remove blank spaces between html tags using html agility pack

Tags: html, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

The next thing you should try doing is that removing leading spaces at the start of para or tag. For e.g. you would find many ref like

```
<p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style='font-size:12.0pt'>                In these
types of levers, the <i>fulcrum</i> F is in between the <i>effort </i>E and the
<i>load </i>L as shown in Fig 3.1 (a).</span></p>
```

This should be converted to

```
<p class="MsoNoSpacing"><span style='font-size:12.0pt'>In these
types of levers, the <i>fulcrum</i> F is in between the <i>effort </i>E and the
<i>load </i>L as shown in Fig 3.1 (a).</span></p>
```

i am using html agility pack i can anyone help me with this

Comment: Whitespace between elements in HTML gets collapsed into a single whitespace when rendered. Can you explain _why_ you need to achieve this? Can you also explain what you have tried with the HAP and where you are stuck?

Comment: i am converting a docx file to html  file which causes this problem  now i want to parse the file and wherever it finds a blank space it should remove it and with HAP i have the following code

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection bn = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span");
           foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode item in bn)
            
            {
               if (item .Attributes.ToString ()=="style")
            {
                string str=item .InnerText .ToString ();
                int flag = 1;
                char[] array = str.ToCharArray();

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < str .Length ; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i] != ' ' )
                        flag = 0;
                }
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    item.ParentNode.RemoveAllChildren();
                }
            }
           }*/